# How to sort data by column in a table view if click to headerview

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` that is populated with a `QSqlQueryModel`. I am trying to sort the table based on which header is checked, but nothing is happening when I press them. I used function `sortByColumn()`
The problem is that the result is exactly the same,when i click the header the sorting is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 Log cnn;
 QSqlQueryModel *modal=new QSqlQueryModel();
 QSqlQuery *qry=new QSqlQuery(cnn.mydb);
 qry->prepare("select *from log");
 qry->exec();
 modal->setQuery(*qry);
 ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
 ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
 ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
 ui->tableView->sortByColumn(4,Qt::AscendingOrder);//4 indicate the 4th column
```

Answer (score 4):

And also i solved my problem using  QSortFilterProxyModel.

```
Log cnn;
QSqlQueryModel *modal=new QSqlQueryModel(this);
QSqlQuery *qry=new QSqlQuery(cnn.mydb);
qry->prepare("select *from AccessLog");
qry->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry);

QSortFilterProxyModel *m=new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
m->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
m->setSourceModel(modal);
ui->tableView->setModel(m);
ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using more than one table then `QSqlTableModel` fits your needs.

instead of using `QSqlQueryModel` you could use

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(this, mydb);
model->setTable("log");
model->select();
model->setHeaderData( 1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("header1") );
model->setHeaderData( 2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("header2") );

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

`QSqlTableModel` has implemented the following:

```
void QSqlTableModel::sort ( int column, Qt::SortOrder order ) [virtual]
```

So you can sort like:

```
model->sort (4, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```